# Unrecoverable error during WUBI installation

Tags: installation, boot, wubi

I tried to install 12.10 on my PC with Windows 7 installed, but I don't have a CD drive and my PC doesn't support USB booting, so I tried the Windows Installer (WUBI). I had the ISO image mounted with daemon tools, so the Windows installer took those files and used them (I guess, because it didn't download any files).

Everything went right, but when it prompted me to reboot, I rebooted the PC and then it starts to install, but when the installation process starts, a message that says:

```
The installation found a unrecoverable error.
```

pops out and makes me reboot, then when I select Ubuntu in the operating system selection screen, it says that `an error occurred`.

Comment: We need the *exact* error messages.

Answer (score 0):

dont mont on damon tools on other programs for that, may result damaged system install.
download iso and download apprpried wubi.exe (if is iso 12.04 wubi.exe must be for 12.04).
put them in same folder and run the wubi.exe. he is do the rest of process i windows.

if this is complicated, you can download just wubi.exe and run it. he is download apprpriet iso image and install OS.

dont mont iso on any tool please...